# Auto-Complete on ngTagsInput: $query keeps empty

Tags: angularjs

I´m using ngTagsInput with auto-complete to filter my TagList:

```
<tags-input ng-model="tags" placeholder="neues Tag">
    <auto-complete source="loadTags($query)"></auto-complete>
</tags-input>
```

And the following js:

```
var app = angular.module('ipbx', ['ngTagsInput']);
var query;

app.controller('MainCtrl', function($scope, $http) {

  $scope.tags = globaltags;


  $scope.loadTags = function(val) {
    return $http.get(tagurl+"&query="+val);
  };

});
```

When I have a least 3 characters in the input, the tagurl is fired, but `$query` keeps `undefined`.

Any Idea?

Answer (score 0):

I don't understand your question, but you can edit the number of char that you want in this File ng-tags-input.min.js

and this parameter

> minLength: [Number, 3],

Is that what you want?

Answer (score 0):

Not really.

I have to ask an url to get appropriate result based on my input für new Tags. So I have to submit the new Tag entered.

Example:

Enter "hal" as new Tag, The folliwing url is called:

```
http://xxxxxx/q=hal
```

By documentation it should be ($query), but in real this value is undefined:

```
http://xxxxxxx/q=undefined
```

Adding of input is done by

```
<auto-complete source="loadTags($query)"></auto-complete>
```

$query seems to be the problem. When I statically enter another textvalue, it works correkt. How can I fill $query with the correct value?

I´ll hope this is a bit more detailled :-)